# Why am I getting errors about API version?

Tags: android

I changed the API version in my manifest to:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

However in my code I'm getting an error:

```
Call requires API level 14 (current min is 11):         
     android.hardware.Camera.Parameters#getMaxNumFocusAreas
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: have you tried. clean then rebuild?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: Rebuild the project (Project -> Clean in Eclipse) and try again.

Comment: Clean fixes it, but if I edit the file again the error comes back...

Comment: That happens. If the API target or min version changes, then a clean will be required.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update the Eclipse settings for the project. Right-click on the project, and look for "Properties -> Android".